# TeamCity automated test on Puppet profiles on GitLab

Tags: git, triggers, teamcity, puppet, gitlab

I wanted to ask if it is possible to make automated tests on TeamCity on my Puppet4 profiles? I keep my Puppet profiles code on GitLab and there is a lot of profiles in single GitLab project, new code is pushed to development branches and then merge request being created.

I want a way to check new merge request for only modified profile on TeamCity, but not for all code.

Is it possible to make trigger for TC server to run tests only for modified profile/hieradata or at least modified files from GitLab on single TC project (I do not want to create TC project for every profile in my Puppet 4, because there is a lot of profiles and new profiles comes pretty often)?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you may need to do some additional work to determine what changed once you are notified of a change by the VCS plugin. TeamCity will kick off your custom check tool that will drive to see what changed and then run just those profiles.

However, I'm not sure there is anything built in that will do this for you.